# hosted service to post software releases for users with signup form?

Tags: service, download, release-management, hosted

I'm a sole developer looking for an online service where I can host files of my software releases for users. I want them to register first before downloading so I can get a sense of who downloaded the software. Does a service like this exist and what would be recommended? I also have manuals that I keep online for the software.